# Why don't Lagrange multipliers work here?

Tags: number-theory, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

I saw this question here [Maximum of $x^3+y^3+z^3$ with $x+y+z=3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2268524/maximum-of-x3y3z3-with-xyz-3) and wanted to try this approach (maximizing $x^3+y^3+z^3$ subject to constraints $x+y+z=3$ and $0 \leq x, y, z \leq 2$).

I tried this:

Let $f(x,y,z) = x^3+y^3+z^3$ and $g(x,y,z) = x+y+z$. Then the Lagrange multiplier equations are:

$$
\begin{align}
x+y+z &= 3 \\
3x^2 &= \lambda \\
3y^2 &= \lambda\\
3z^2 &= \lambda \\
\end{align}$$

This implies $\lambda = 3$ with $x=y=z=1$ but clearly this doesn't maximize $f$ as much as setting $x,y,z=0,2,1$. What's the deal?

Comment: Probably that's a local minimum and the maximum is achieved somewhere on the boundary.

Comment: A lagrange multiplier equation in this case would be set up with three more constrains of $x,,z$

Comment: Adding constraints in what way?

Comment: Like $\lambda_1(2-x)+\lambda_2(2-y)+\lambda_3(2-z)$ would have been the additional material

Comment: Moreover that doesn't maximize ,it rather minimizes the expression.You really need to be sure of what you've got,whether it's a maximum or an minimum